# We used floating point numbers instead of real numbers in NICE programming language. Why?

Tags: automata, computation-theory, computation

In The NICE programming language,we use floating point numbers instead of real numbers. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a discussion that applies to all programming languages, not just NICE. There are books written about this, but in summary:

Computers store information in binary, and it's hard to store our decimal (base-10) numbers in binary. A long time ago, we made a standard format for dealing with non-integer numbers in a **performance-conscious** manner: IEEE 754, which has come to be widely recognized.

We keep using it because it works and it is successful. Our hardware is made around it. Programmers have fine-tuned the way we work with floating point numbers. It's sensible to keep using it.